# Especific Query in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

i have an entity with my products, an i have a relation of one to many to another entity with the types and prices for each product.
In my galery view, i want to bring all the products with their types and prices respectively, to do something like this:

```
{% for product in products%}
    <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
    <p>Description: {{ product.description }}</p>

    <table>
        <tr>

            {% for type in types %}

                <td>{{ type.type }}</td>

            {% endfor %}

         </tr>

         <tr>
             {% for type in types %}

                <td>{{ type.price }}</td>

             {% endfor %}
         </tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

i think that i have to do only one query, where i find all the products with their prices and types. But I do not know how.

i have exactly this:

***Catalogo.php***

```
Class Catalogo {

/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="articulo", type="string", length=70, unique = true)
     */
    private $articulo;

/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Unidades", mappedBy="catalogo")
     */
    protected $unidades;
```

***Medidas.php***

```
Class Medidas{

/**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="medida", type="float")
     */
    private $medida;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="precio", type="float")
     */
    private $precio;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Catalogo", inversedBy="unidades", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="catalogo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $catalogo;
```

And i do this, but it doesnt work:

```
public function findByArticuloYPrecios()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository('ProyectoAdminBundle:Catalogo');
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('Catalogo')
        ->select("Catalogo, Unidades")
        ->from("Catalogo", "catalogo")
        ->leftJoin("catalogo.unidades", "medida")
        ->getQuery();

        try 
        {
            return $query->getResult();
        }


        catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The function return null.

Comment: Read [Doctrine Query Builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have for example:

Product and some types in relation try to do this just like this:

```
 $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('Catalogo')
    ->select("catalogo, unidades")
    ->from("Catalogo", "catalogo")
    ->leftJoin("catalogo.unidades", "unidades")
    ->getQuery()
```

Comment: In the second line you put the properties, in the third the name of the entity, and the property, and finally in the quarter line, the link and the property ???

Comment: Second: aliases to entities (aliases of mapped DB objects) Third: Product entity and its alias, Fourth: join type and its alias

Comment: Can you check what i modificated, because it doesnt work??

Comment: Try something like this above. and one more thing. If you create classes/write some code please do this in english. It is more clear.

Comment: Sorry but i am from Argentina. The code doesnt work. For me, the second line are the name of the properties that you are requesting, the theird line, the name of the entity and the alias, finally the fourth line, you have to put the link property and it alias. What you think ?